# javascript how to find number of children in an object

Tags: javascript, object

is there a way to find the number of children in a javascript object other than running a loop and using a counter? I can leverage jquery if it will help. I am doing this:

```
var childScenesObj = [];
var childScenesLen = scenes[sceneID].length; //need to find number of children of scenes[sceneID]. This obviously does not work, as it an object, not an array.


for (childIndex in scenes[sceneID].children) {
    childSceneObj = new Object();
    childSceneID = scenes[sceneID].children[childIndex];
    childSceneNode = scenes[childSceneID];
    childSceneObj.name = childSceneNode.name;
    childSceneObj.id = childSceneID;
    childScenesObj  .push(childSceneObj);
}
```

Comment: waiting to pounce on jquery based answers...

Comment: You are making a new `childScenesObj` at each iteration in the loop, then pushing it onto itself. I don't think this will work out. You need another `var` in there

Comment: Are you asking about DOM elements or plain old JavaScript objects?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The following works in ECMAScript5 (Javascript 1.85)

```
var x = {"1":1, "A":2};
Object.keys(x).length; //outputs 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If that object is actually an Array, .length will always get you the number of indexes.  If you're referring to an object and you want to get the number of attributes/keys in the object, there's no way I know to that other than a counter:

```
var myArr = [];
alert(myArr.length);// 0
myArr.push('hi');
alert(myArr.length);// 1

var myObj = {};
myObj["color1"] = "red";
myObj["color2"] = "blue";

// only way I know of to get "myObj.length"
var myObjLen = 0;
for(var key in myObj)
  myObjLen++;
```

Comment: You need to filter enumerable properties from the prototype in that `for...in` loop using [`Object.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Comment: Can you post a fiddle that demonstrates the need? Never run into an issue with key enumeration before....  would be very keen to see it...

Comment: Something like this: `for(var key in obj) if((Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj,key) && Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(obj,key)) length++;` This is bad-code proof :)

Comment: @Matt Ball - your fiddle breaks in IE and FFX.

Comment: This is wrong. The length property of an array returns its largest index, not the number of indices. For an object, use `Object.keys(myObj).length`

Comment: Well, if that *`Object`* is actually an `Array`, then it's an *`Array`*, not an `Object`...