# Javascript Get length of list of items in object?

Tags: javascript, object, content-length

I currently have a Javascript object that looks like this:

`Object {0: 8, 1: 9, 2: 10}`

I am trying to get the number of individual items in the object (i.e. 3) but can't figure out how to do so. Since the object isn't an array, I can't just call `.length()`. I tried `huntsList[2].toString().split('.').length` to split the items at the commas and count them in this way but it returns 1, since it converts the entire object to a single string that looks like this: `["[object Object]"]`.

Any suggestions for how I can accomplish this are appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [javascript how to find number of children in an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081165/javascript-how-to-find-number-of-children-in-an-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get object length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533192/how-to-get-object-length)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could get the keys using `Object.keys`, which returns an array of the keys:

[Example](https://jsbin.com/fugesu/1/edit?js,console)

```
var obj = {0: 8, 1: 9, 2: 10};

var keys = Object.keys(obj);

var len = keys.length
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Object.keys()`. It returns an array of the keys of an object.

```
var myObject = {0: 8, 1: 9, 2: 10};
console.log(Object.keys(myObject).length)
```

Answer (score 5):

1: ES5.1 solution use Object.keys - returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties

```js
var obj = {
  0: 8,
  1: 9,
  2: 10
}
console.log(Object.keys(obj).length)
```

2: Pre-ES5 Solution: use for..in and hasOwn

```js
var obj = {
  0: 8,
  1: 9,
  2: 10
};

var propsLength = 0;
for (prop in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    propsLength = propsLength + 1;
  }
}
console.log(propsLength);
```

3: Library Solution: Use lodash/underscore Convert it to an array, and query its length, if you need a pure js solution, we can look into how toArray works.

```js
console.log(_.toArray({
  0: 8,
  1: 9,
  2: 10
}).length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {0: 8, 1: 9, 2: 10};
alert(Object.keys(obj).length);
```

with this code, try to alert the length of you object mate.!