# Check if number of children greater than 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How do I check if the number of children of a node is greater than 1 in Cloud Functions for Firebase? In my case I want to see if the number of days is > 1

For example:

```
if(children of 'messages' node > 1)
// do something
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Three Options, depending on your use case:

**One.** Retrieve the `messages` object and count the keys, e.g.

```
var x = {"1":1, "A":2};
Object.keys(x).length; //outputs 2
```

[from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7081431/4221083)

---

**Two.** More favorable, keep a `count` node as a child of `messages` and monitor when children are added and deleted. Firebase has provided an example on how to do that:

[Here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/child-count/functions/index.js)

---

**Three**. You can also use `numChildren()` for the top level of the snapshot.

[numChildren](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#numChildren)

Example:

```
// If the number of likes gets deleted, recount the number of likes
exports.countDays = functions.database.ref('/messages').onWrite(event => {
    const theRef = event.data.ref;
    const collectionRef = theRef.parent.child('days');
    collectionRef.once('value').then(messagesData => {
        if(messagesData.numChildren()) > 1) {
            // do something
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I updated my question with my data structure. How would I count the number of days in my case?

Comment: For example, `if(days.children > 1) //do something`

Comment: Great. how would I use `numChildren()` precisely in my case?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question, I was not clear enough. When `onWrite` on the `messages` node. I want to check if days > 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using just 7 days of the week you could just loop over an array with the week days and do this:

```
function amountOfChildren(ref, arr) {
  let children = 0;
  for (const item in arr) {
    if ref.hasChild(item) {children++}
  }
  return children;
}

const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
const daysRef = rootRef.child('days');
const weekDays = ["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday"];
amountOfChildren(daysRef, weekDays); // returns a number from 0 to 7
```